# Project directory accidentally in sys.path - how to remove it?

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I don't know how it happened, but my `sys.path` now apparently contains the path to my local Python project directory, let's call that `/home/me/my_project`. (Ubuntu).

`echo $PATH` does not contain that path and `echo $PYTHONPATH` is empty.

I am currently preparing distribution of the package and playing with `setup.py`, trying to always work in an virtualenv. Perhaps I messed something up while not having a virtualenv active. Though I trying to re-install using `python3 setup.py --record` (in case I did an accidental install) fails with insufficient privileges - so I probably didn't accidentally install it into the system python.

Does anyone have an idea how to track down how my module path got to the sys.path and how to remove that?

Comment: What is your current working directory?

Comment: [the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Comment: The directory is in the sys.path no matter where I invoke `python` from. It is also not `sys.path[0]` but somewhere „in the middle“.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't have the full understanding of my solution, but here it is nonetheless.

### My solution

Remove my package from `site-packages/easy-install.pth`

### (An attempt at) explanation

The first hurdle is to understand that `PYTHONPATH` only gets *added to* `sys.path`, but is not necessarily equal to it. We are thus after what adds the package into `sys.path`.

The variable `sys.path` is defined by `site.py`.

One of the things `site.py` does is automatically add packages from `site-packages` into `sys.path`.

In my case, I incorrectly installed my package as a site-package, causing it to get added to `easy-install.pth` in `site-packages` and thus its path into `sys.path`.